# XSLT: How do I get this output?

Tags: xml, xslt

Here's the XML:

```
<list title="Shopping list">
   <item>Orange juice</item>
   <item>Bread</item>
   <item>
      <list title="Cake ingredients">
         <item>Flour</item>
         <item>Eggs</item>
         <item>Milk</item>
         <item>Sugar</item>
         <item>
            <list title="Chocolate icing ingredients"
      </list>
      <item>Cocoa powder</item>
      <item>Icing mixture</item>
      <item>Unsalted butter</item>
</list>
</item>
</list>
</item>
</list>
```

The required output is to be:

Shopping list:
1 Bread
Cake ingredients
2.1 Chocolate icing ingredients:
2.1.1 Cocoa powder
2.1.2 Icing mixture
2.1.3 Unsalted butter
2.2 Eggs
2.3 Flour
2.4 Milk
2.5 Sugar
3 Orange juice

How would I go about doing this? I was able to use position() to number some nodes and sort to sort some elements, but I wasn't able to do all of it.

Comment: You said you'd been able to use position () to number the nodes, so show us what you've done so far.

Comment: Do you actually want to output just text here? Or are you actually trying to output HTML?

Comment: @TimC I want to output the text

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed, so it's difficult to understand the logic required.

Comment: For most numbering in XSLT, it's best to look at <xsl:number> - trying to use position() will usually, for hierarchical numbering, cause the code to become excessively complex.

Answer (score 0):

You did not state it explicitly, but I noticed that:

- The elements to include at a particular level should include:

  - "leaf" `item` elements (with no descendant node),
    the text to print is their content,
  - `list` elements - children of "non-leaf" `item` elements,
    but this time the text to print is their `title` attribute.
- The required ordering at a particular level is the text to be printed.

To obtain the required recursion, the script should start with
applying a template to the root `list` element and then apply templates
to the elements at the next level.

I wrote one "universal" template for both cases (`list` and leaf `item`
elements).

This template has 2 optional parameters:

- `nr` - element number (at this level),
- `prefix` - cumulated numbers from higher levels.

`pref` variable contains the "composed" (multi-level) number to be printed
and also to be used in the recursive template application.

The last part of this template includes 2 variants, for `list`
and `item` respectively.

The `list` variant:

- prints `title` attribute,
- selects elements for the next level,
- and in a sorted loop applies the template to them.

The `item` variant just prints the content.

So the whole script looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="list"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="list | item[not(*)]">
    <xsl:param name="nr" required="no" select="0"/>
    <xsl:param name="prefix" required="no" select="''"/>
    <xsl:variable name="pref" select="
      if ($nr = 0) then ''
      else if ($prefix) then concat($prefix, '.', $nr)
      else $nr"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="
      if ($pref) then concat($pref, ' ')
      else ''"/>
    <xsl:if test="name()='list'">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(@title, '&#xA;')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="items" select="item[not(*)] | item/list"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$items">
        <xsl:sort select="if (name() = 'list') then @title else ."/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
          <xsl:with-param name="nr" select="position()"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="$pref"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="name()!='list'">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

The only difference between "your" output and "mine" is that
my script prints also the number for `list` elements (actually
only *Cake ingredients*).

I thought, you had just forgotten about the number in front of
this element.

Note also that *2.1.* without *2* before looks unnatural.